# Value of $ f(2012)$

Tags: functions

$f(x) $ is an injective function . The definition of $f(x)$ is like following:

$$
f:[0, \infty[\to \Bbb R-\{0\},
f\left(x + \frac{1}{f(y)}\right) = \frac{f(x)f(y)}{f(x) + f(y)} $$

If $f(0) = 1$ then what is the value of $ f(2012)$?

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Just a remark : $f(x)$ is NOT a function, it is a real number here. $f$ is a function !

Comment: Can you calculate $f(1)$? How about $f(2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f\left(x+ \frac{1}{f(y)} \right) = \frac{f(x)f(y)}{f(x)+f(y)}$ and $f(0)=1$

i.e., for $x=-\frac{1}{f(y)}$ we have $\frac{f(x).\frac{-1}{x}}{f(x)-\frac{1}{x}}=1$

$\frac{-f(x)}{xf(x)-1}=1$ i.e.,$-f(x)=xf(x)-1$ i.e., $f(x)(x+1)=1$ i.e., $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$

This would give $f(x)$ for any $x$ in the domain.

in particular $f(2012)=\frac{1}{2013}$

Answer (score 4):

You can check that
$$
f\left(0 + \frac{1}{f(0)}\right) = \frac{f(0)f(0)}{f(0) + f(0)} \Rightarrow f(1) = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Now assume that $f(n-1) = 1/n$, then
$$
f(n) = f\left(0 + \frac{1}{f(n-1)}\right) = \frac{f(0)f(n-1)}{f(0) + f(n-1)} = \frac{1}{n+1}
$$
Hence,
$$
f(2012) = \frac{1}{2013}
$$